# export large database mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, fatal-error

I am using phpmyadmin on my windows os. I have a database with one table which has 100M records with the size of 20GB. I want to export this table and have the table.sql file. Whenever I try to do this, the size of the exported file is 0 bytes. When I check the apache error log, the following would show up:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1066139648 bytes)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest to try using the command line and the mysqldump.exe utility, as suggested [here](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/news/importexport-large-mysql-databases)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I did to solve my problem.

Comment: you're welcome, i'm happy to help ! phpmyadmin is a usefull tool ans makes many things simpler to administrate a Mysql DB, but it has its limitations...
Cheers

Comment: That's a good answer. I don't have the gzip installed in my system. So, I used 'sql.zip' instead of 'sql.gz' while exporting. Then, I imported on PHPMyAdmin with the 'interrupt after PHP timeout' unchecked. That worked :)

Answer (score 17):

If you have shared hosting and you are using **Cpanel** then they are providing you the option to backup your database in the following section.

**Files** => **Backup** => **Download a MySQL Database Backup**.

Answer (score 10):

If you are on a shared hosting or you don't have access to shell, then use [mysqldumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/) script; copy it to your server and start it in your browser under "yourDomain.com/path_to_mysqlumper/"

[image: MySQLDumper is a PHP and Perl based tool for backing up MySQL databases. You can easily dump your data into a backup file and - if needed - restore it. It is especially suited for shared hosting webspaces, where you don't have shell access.]

> MySQLDumper is a PHP and Perl based tool for backing up MySQL
>   databases. You can easily dump your data into a backup file and - if
>   needed - restore it. It is especially suited for shared hosting
>   webspaces, where you don't have shell access.

If you have shell access to your host servers  (if provided by your host since not all shared server hosters give this access) then you may use SSH access like in this [tutorial](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/180) using [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) that you [install and configure](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/301) then import or export your databases like in this [third tutorial](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/112).

Comment: Looks like a dead link.

Answer (score 3):

I try **mysqldump**  for many hours but didnt work, until I started a superuser console.

First, start a superuser console

```
sudo su
```

Then, try the complete command

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u root -p [DATABASE NAME] > [PATH_FOR_BACKUPFILE]/[FILE_NAME].sql
```

I my case, it was something like **/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u root -p database > /home/user/backup.sql**

Answer (score 1):

MySQLDumper worked like a charm for me at my hosted website. I had to copy one database and "paste" it into a new database. In MySQLDumper, it isn't apparent right away how to do this, but the key is to create a new configuration file in MySQLDumper and that will allow you to copy/restore to different databases.

On the home screen in MySQLDumper, click Configuration, then Configuration Files. There is a text box at the top allowing you to create a new Configuration file. In there, put in the information for the second database you need (you created a connection to the first database when you install MySQLDumper). Save it. Then you can click Restore where you can select the dump of the first database and restore it in the second one.

This was a lifesaver. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

increase

> max_post_size

variable in php.ini file. Then you will be able to download it.

Answer (score -1):

I had a different issue when I was downloading from phpmyadmin in the middle like 180MB  download stops with message - network error

So I used ssh connection which you can find in your cpanel sometimes they provide browser based terminal or sometime you have to access it using putty .

In terminal I go inside my `public_html` folder where all my files are stored . Followed by this command:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [database-you-want-to-dump] > [path-to-place-data-dump.sql]
```

This did the job in few minutes and saved a sql file in my `public_html` folder. Then I opened the folder in File manager and downloaded it from there.

You can also use FTP or you can download it directory by accessing by url.

**Make sure you delete it after your download finishes**.